# Range sort using multiple criteria

Tags: vba, excel, sorting

I have the following data in col GA and GB respectively

```
GA   GB
1   strn
2   accn
6   thon
8   advn
9   estn
14  actn
17  cngn
37  autn
49  empn
```

And I use the following auto generated code to do A->Z sort with col `GA` being the key range.

```
   Columns("GA:GB").Select
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("CSV Dump").Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("CSV Dump").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("GA1"), _
        SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("CSV Dump").Sort
        .SetRange Range("GA1:GB9")
        .Header = xlNo
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
```

My question if col GA has duplicate values like following:

```
GA   GB
1   strn
2   accn
2   thon
8   advn
9   estn
14  actn
17  cngn
37  autn
49  empn
```

then how can I modify the code or by any other means sort the col GB from Z->A only for the range in col GA which has duplicates?

> Expected output:

```
GA   GB
1   strn
2   thon
2   accn
8   advn
9   estn
14  actn
17  cngn
37  autn
49  empn
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is add a second sort level. That means after

```
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("CSV Dump").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("GA1"), _
    SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
```

You'll want to enter a similar line but referencing the GB column with the reverse order.

```
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("CSV Dump").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("GB1"), _
    SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
```